# CiviMail - How do I change the sender email account?

Tags: civimail, email

I am trying to send a Thank You email to our donor contributors through CiviMail. We have a message template set up. But our test emails keep showing the wrong sender email account "info@email.com" instead of our goal "donations@email.com." The latter email address is already set up in our From Email Address and Mail Accounts. The CiviCRM manual mentioned that there was a dropdown to change the sender? But I don't see this option anywhere. Please advise.

Stacy

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Can you please update your question with what version of CiviCRM you are running, as well as what CMS platform and version (Drupal, Wordpress or Joomla?). This will ensure that the community can provide a more specific answer.

Answer (score 3):

The drop-down for the 'from' (sender) email address is on the first page of the mailing screen which is called the 'Define Mailing' screen. The drop-down is appropriately named 'From' with an asterisk by it to denote that it's mandatory. It's likely that you need to look at the 'from' email address table (Administer/CiviMail/From Email Addresses) and check what the default is.  This assumes you're using 4.6 or greater.